# Cut vector into groups

Tags: r

```
a <- -30:30
cutSize <- 10
b <- a %/% cutSize
table(b)
# Output
-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
10 10 10 10 10 10  1
```

**Wanted output**

```
-3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
10 10 10  1 10 10  10
```

I need to divide vector into groups (by `cutSize`). Always used `%/%`, but apparently it "shifts" my groups. 
I want to group:

- zero to group `0`
- Everything from 1 to 10 to group `1`
- From 11 to 20 to group `2`
- ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a bit awkword solution

```
table(ceiling((a / cutSize) * sign(a)) * sign(a))
# -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
# 10 10 10  1 10 10 10
```

Or similarly

```
table(ceiling(abs(a / cutSize)) * sign(a))
# -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3 
# 10 10 10  1 10 10 10
```